# Node read stream hangs on specific file, base64 encoding

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have following code working for every file except one that keeps hanging without emitting `end` or `error` events (I tried other stream events too).

```
const fs = require('fs');

const rs = fs.createReadStream(filePath, {
    encoding: 'base64',
});

rs.on('data', () => {
    console.log('data');
});
rs.on('end', () => {
    console.log('end');
});
rs.on('error', e => {
    console.log('error', e);
});
```

If I move read point with `start` option to 1 instead of 0 it works properly. Same if `highWaterMark` is set to value other than default. It doesn't really help as it seems it can fail with other "corrupted" file.

It seems like Node bug, but maybe there's something I'm missing here.

I'll post file in here too, but first I need to strip it to down to only corrupting part as it's somewhat private.

---

**Update**

Here's file to recreate the issue:
http://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/jjapitest/file

**Update**

Here's interactive demo of the issue:
https://repl.it/repls/AnimatedDisguisedNumerator

Comment: Do you have a use case that does not allow you to use fs.readFile?  Its much simpler to use if you can.

Comment: It's actually external library that does it using buffers. And it's not going to be used for loading too big files, so certainly `readFile` is good fit, but I still want know what's going on.